# is Observable.toPromise and Observable.last().subscribe are identical

Tags: rxjs, observable

are this two line of code are identical in performance

```
Observable.range(1,5).toPromise().then(res => console.log(res))
```

vs

```
Observable.range(1,5).last().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up [the documentation of `toPromise()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/toPromise.js.html#lineNumber52) you will find that its nearly identical

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let value;
    this.subscribe((x) => value = x, (err) => reject(err), () => resolve(value));
});
```